# Extension of the Phragmén-Lindelöf Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, maximum-principle

[image]

Above is the statement of the theorem. And below is the exercise I am stuck at. I think I have to figure out the extended boundary of V∩G and apply the original theorem to V∩G. However, I can't figure out the extended boundary of V∩G at all.... Could anyone please help me how to extend the Phragmén-Lindelöf Theorem?

[image]

Comment: which book is this from? :)

Comment: Conway's functions of one complex variable